# vb.NET Data to SVG

Tags: xml, vb.net, svg

How do you write data in the right format to an SVG file? I got a bunch of data which I want to write to a SVG file. but cant find any information of how to write data from a VB.net project to the right format in SVG.

Below I added an example of how my data should look in the SVG,

```
  <svg width="900" height="900" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g transform="translate(50, 50) scale(0.853380064526) translate(-115526.879922, 400503.660232)">

                <path d="M 115758.480393 -399904.510586 L 115753.195776 -399905.465941L 115755.152047 -399916.287195L 115744.721126 -399918.172901" stroke="orange" stroke-width="1" fill="none" />

                    <text font-size="4" font-family="sans-serif" fill="black" stroke="none" text-anchor="middle" 
                          x="115767.145248" y="-399900.893901"></text>
```

So I advanced a bit but hit another rock... Apperantly you cant use spaces in XML elements. but to get the above format I need to divide my data with spaces. this is my code so far:

```
    'declare our xmlwritersettings object
    Dim settings As New XmlWriterSettings()

        'lets create the MyXML.xml document, the first parameter was the Path/filename of xml file
        ' the second parameter was our xml settings
        Dim XmlWrt As XmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("C:\Users\s\Desktop\MyXML.svg", settings)

        With XmlWrt

            ' Write the Xml declaration.
            .WriteStartDocument()

            ' Write the root element.
            .WriteStartElement("svg width=" & SVGWidht & " height=" & SVGheight & " xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg""")

            'write the svg setting
            .WriteStartElement("g transform=""translate(40, 40) scale(" & schaal & ") translate(0, 0)""")

            'string voor kaderrand
            Dim StringKader As String = kadermarge & " " & kadermarge & " L " & SVGWidht - kadermarge & " " & kadermarge & " " & SVGWidht - kadermarge & " " & SVGheight - kadermarge & " " & kadermarge & " " & SVGheight - kadermarge & " " & kadermarge & " " & kadermarge

            'draw border
            .WriteStartElement("path d=""M " & StringKader & " stroke=""Black"" stroke-width=""1"" fill=""none""/")

            .WriteEndElement()


            ' The end of SVG settings
            .WriteEndElement()

            ' The end of the SGV.
            .WriteEndElement()

            ' Close the XmlTextWriter.
            .WriteEndDocument()
            .Close()

        End With
```

So anyone have an idea how it can get the needed format and work around the white space issue?

Comment: is this comment essentially 'how do I write xml from a vb.net project?'

Comment: I know how to get a dataset with datatables in an XML but I cant figure out how to get it in this format.

Comment: You should show how your data is currently formatted, and any attempt at writing so far.

Comment: Currently it is data in DGV's (X,Y coordinates, pointnames and line colors) and all the other data I need is in variabales or calculated in my program